# ASP.Net Displaying the data dynamically on the screen

Tags: asp.net

How to display the data on the webpage when it is entered using the form. Data should get added and appended. Database use is prohibited

e.g

```
     Step 1)I/p Name:Laptop
            Color:Black
            O/p Laptop, <Black>

     Step 2)I/p Name:Car
            Color:White
            O/p Car, <White>
            Laptop, <Black>

      Step 3)I/p Name:Laptop
             Color:Red
             O/p Car, <White>
             Laptop, <Black,Red>
```

Comment: Use datatable or dataset

Comment: You need to be more detailed as to what you want to do, your examples are not clear at all.

Comment: Those job interview tests are amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one user is going to enter data and see it directly, you should consider on click on submit button:

- saving data in list of objects in the page
- binding the list with gridview or repeater or any data container you like..
- put the gridview inside updatepanel and set the submit button as the trigger for this update panel to update

If another user is going to do the input you should consider files. Save data delimited with comma or any other delimiter in file and do file processing on page load to display data.